# Franklin U772 (U700 series) usb modem - can't connect

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, networking, usb, modem

trying to get my Raspberry Pi 3 connected using USA Sprint's modem **Franklin U772**.

system is:

```
Linux raspberrypi 4.9.41-v7+ #1023 SMP Tue Aug 8 16:00:15 BST 2017 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

According to specifications modem offers Ethernet over usb (RNDIS) as connection interface.

Upon plugin modem is succesfully detected and usb0 interface is assigned to RNDIS device, see **/var/log/syslog** cut:

```
Feb  2 08:15:09 raspberrypi kernel: [   21.200561] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 5 using dwc_otg
Feb  2 08:15:09 raspberrypi kernel: [   21.331448] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=1fac, idProduct=0232
Feb  2 08:15:09 raspberrypi kernel: [   21.331464] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=4
Feb  2 08:15:09 raspberrypi kernel: [   21.331472] usb 1-1.2: Product: Franklin 700 USB Modem
Feb  2 08:15:09 raspberrypi kernel: [   21.331480] usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: Franklin Wireless Corp.
Feb  2 08:15:09 raspberrypi kernel: [   21.331488] usb 1-1.2: SerialNumber: 0123456789ABCDEF
Feb  2 08:15:09 raspberrypi kernel: [   21.554784] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_ether
Feb  2 08:15:09 raspberrypi kernel: [   21.564209] rndis_host 1-1.2:1.0 usb0: register 'rndis_host' at usb-3f980000.usb-1.2, RNDIS device, 7e:25:06:37:b7:31
Feb  2 08:15:09 raspberrypi kernel: [   21.564373] usbcore: registered new interface driver rndis_host
Feb  2 08:15:09 raspberrypi kernel: [   26.022404] usb 1-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 5
Feb  2 08:15:09 raspberrypi kernel: [   26.022603] rndis_host 1-1.2:1.0 usb0: unregister 'rndis_host' usb-3f980000.usb-1.2, RNDIS device
Feb  2 08:15:09 raspberrypi kernel: [   26.400559] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 6 using dwc_otg
Feb  2 08:15:09 raspberrypi kernel: [   26.541424] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=1fac, idProduct=0232
Feb  2 08:15:09 raspberrypi kernel: [   26.541436] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=4
Feb  2 08:15:09 raspberrypi kernel: [   26.541444] usb 1-1.2: Product: Franklin 700 USB Modem
Feb  2 08:15:09 raspberrypi kernel: [   26.541452] usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: Franklin Wireless Corp.
Feb  2 08:15:09 raspberrypi kernel: [   26.541460] usb 1-1.2: SerialNumber: 0123456789ABCDEF
Feb  2 08:15:09 raspberrypi kernel: [   26.566812] rndis_host 1-1.2:1.0 usb0: register 'rndis_host' at usb-3f980000.usb-1.2, RNDIS device, 96:e9:5e:81:6b:bd
Feb  2 08:15:09 raspberrypi kernel: [   26.619390] cdc_acm 1-1.2:1.2: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
Feb  2 08:15:09 raspberrypi kernel: [   26.623541] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_acm
Feb  2 08:15:09 raspberrypi kernel: [   26.623549] cdc_acm: USB Abstract Control Model driver for USB modems and ISDN adapters
```

I put into **/etc/network/interfaces**:

```
iface usb0 inet dhcp
```

**ifconfig -a** shows:

```
usb0: flags=4098<BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 72:72:02:b1:0a:4c  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

now trying to raise interface: **sudo ifup usb0**:

```
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.3.5
Copyright 2004-2016 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/

/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf line 15: option definitions may only appear in the outermost scope.
option rfc3442-classless-static-routes code 
                                        ^
Listening on LPF/eth0/b8:27:eb:82:21:0e
Sending on   LPF/eth0/b8:27:eb:82:21:0e
Listening on LPF/usb0/72:72:02:b1:0a:4c
Sending on   LPF/usb0/72:72:02:b1:0a:4c
Sending on   Socket/fallback
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 4
DHCPDISCOVER on usb0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3
DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.10.2 on usb0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67
DHCPOFFER of 192.168.10.2 from 192.168.10.1
DHCPACK of 192.168.10.2 from 192.168.10.1
Too few arguments.
Too few arguments.
bound to 192.168.10.2 -- renewal in 381879 seconds.
```

Interface is up with IP of 192.168.10.2, but it is not connected to internet:
**ping -c 5 -I usb0 8.8.8.8**

```
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) from 192.168.10.2 usb0: 56(84) bytes of data.

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 4181ms
```

however, web server, running on modem (192.168.10.1) is up and shows connection is on.

**Upd:**

I can ping 102.168.10.1 thru usb0.

**route -n**:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.168.1   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.3.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.10.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 usb0
192.168.168.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

What should be done to make it work?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Start by not fiddling with ` /etc/network/interfaces` - see [How to set up networking/WiFi](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)
It may or may need additional settings, but you are obviously doing something else you aren't telling us about, as you seem to have 3 different sub-nets.

Comment: Got it done! - problem was in general network configuration, thanks to @Milliways - link provided pushed not into solution, but in solution direction :)